# Socket.io lost connection after few minutes but only with NGINX proxy enabled

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, proxy

I have a problem with socket.io. When I start my Nodejs App Sockets works correctly but after few minutes the connection to websocket is closed and after reconnecting Socket.io fires emit again.
I'm using NGINX Proxy and I have noticed that bypassing NGINX the problem is solved, which configuration I need to edit? I think that the problem is my nginx configuration.

This is my NGINX default config:

```
server { 
listen 80; #listen for all the HTTP requests 
server_name example.com www.example.com; 
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri; }


server {
  server_name    example.com;
  listen       443 ssl http2;


#Optimize Webserver work
#client_max_body_size 16M;
keepalive_timeout 20;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate  /root/social/ssl/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /root/social/ssl/key.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5430;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}

upstream io_nodes {
 server 127.0.0.1:5430;
 keepalive 20;
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should add another parameter:

```
proxy_read_timeout 96000;
```

The default value is 60s. You will get a message "lost connect" after 60s idles with the default value.